# How to save Skeleton Tracking DaTA of OpenNI?

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing a school project which is a Kinect Robosapien project for the Robosapien to do my movements in front of the Kinect (google quick cheap robosapien kinect). I can already track the Skeleton with my Kinect (for Xbox)  and I am using the OpenNI SDK and not the Microsoft Kinect for Windows SDK. I wanted to know how can I save the Skeleton Data and then transform that data into the commands for the Robosapien? I used the code in the Processing IDE which is this:

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;
 
SimpleOpenNI  context;
 
void setup()
{
  // instantiate a new context
  context = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
 
  // enable depthMap generation 
  context.enableDepth();
 
  // enable skeleton generation for all joints
  context.enableUser(SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_PROFILE_ALL);
 
  background(200,0,0);
  stroke(0,0,255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  smooth();
 
  // create a window the size of the depth information
  size(context.depthWidth(), context.depthHeight()); 
}
 
void draw()
{
  // update the camera
  context.update();
 
  // draw depth image
  image(context.depthImage(),0,0); 

  // for all users from 1 to 10
  int i;
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
    // check if the skeleton is being tracked
    if(context.isTrackingSkeleton(i))
    {
      drawSkeleton(i);  // draw the skeleton
    }
  }
}
 
// draw the skeleton with the selected joints
void drawSkeleton(int userId)
{  
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_HEAD, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_NECK);
 
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_NECK, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_SHOULDER);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_SHOULDER, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_ELBOW);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_ELBOW, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_HAND);
 
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_NECK, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_SHOULDER);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_SHOULDER, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_ELBOW);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_ELBOW, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_HAND);
 
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_SHOULDER, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_TORSO);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_SHOULDER, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_TORSO);
 
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_TORSO, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_HIP);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_HIP, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_KNEE);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_KNEE, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_LEFT_FOOT);
 
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_TORSO, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_HIP);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_HIP, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_KNEE);
  context.drawLimb(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_KNEE, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_RIGHT_FOOT);  
}
 
// Event-based Methods
 
// when a person ('user') enters the field of view
void onNewUser(int userId)
{
  println("New User Detected - userId: " + userId);
 
// start pose detection
  context.startPoseDetection("Psi",userId);
}
 
// when a person ('user') leaves the field of view 
void onLostUser(int userId)
{
  println("User Lost - userId: " + userId);
}
 
// when a user begins a pose
void onStartPose(String pose,int userId)
{
  println("Start of Pose Detected - userId: " + userId + ", pose: " + pose);
 
  // stop pose detection
  context.stopPoseDetection(userId); 

  // start attempting to calibrate the skeleton
  context.requestCalibrationSkeleton(userId, true); 
}
 
// when calibration begins
void onStartCalibration(int userId)
{
  println("Beginning Calibration - userId: " + userId);
}
 
// when calibaration ends - successfully or unsucessfully 
void onEndCalibration(int userId, boolean successfull)
{
  println("Calibration of userId: " + userId + ", successfull: " + successfull);
 
  if (successfull) 
  { 
    println(" User calibrated !!!");
 
    // begin skeleton tracking
    context.startTrackingSkeleton(userId); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    println(" Failed to calibrate user !!!");
 
    // Start pose detection
    context.startPoseDetection("Psi",userId);
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60606/how-to-save-skeleton-tracking-data-of-openni?/) by [Dylan8slb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4673/dylan8slb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder, if you are actually using ROS? If yes, please state the distribution (e.g. Groovy) and system (e.g. Linux 64bit) you are using. If no, start using it! :-) My suggestion: start with the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

In any case, I can recommend you have a look at the [OpenNI tracker](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker). It uses the information from the Kinect and outputs transforms/poses for the various body parts (i.e. torso, head, hands etc.). If you want to store this data, you can use [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) to do so.

PS: In case you have no interest in ROS at all, I recommend you use other sites for help, e.g. [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). You probably get better help there, since this Q&A here is targeted at ROS-specific issues.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3